# Python and double quotes formulas to excel

Tags: python, excel, formula

I all.

I have a problem to insert a formula in exce cell.
I have this dictionary

```
di_count = {'Vacation Count': '=COUNTIF(E6:NF6;"V")',
            'Permit Count': '=AVERAGE(E6:NF6)',
            }
df_empList = pd.DataFrame(di_count)

# Loc test
df_empList.loc[<index>, <column>] = '=COUNTIF(E6:NF6;"V")'  

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')
        writer.book = load_workbook(filename)        


df_empList.to_excel(writrer, 'Sheet10', startrow=1, startcol=1, header=False, **to_excel_kwargs)
```

=COUNTIF(E6:NF6;"V") not work, Excel remove formula when I open file:
=AVERAGE(E6:NF6) work fine. 
All formulas with a Double Quote (") not working.

I have try different variants, bu without success

```
=COUNTIF(E6:NF6;\"V\")
=COUNTIF(E6:NF6;""V"")
```

EDIT: I have added some information

Any suggestions?

Regards, 
Marco

EDIT:
This is the complete code.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter


df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
"Formula": ['=COUNTIF($E2:$G6;"10")', '=AVERAGE($E3:$G3)', '=SUM($E4:$G4)', '=MAX($E4:$G4)', '=MIN($E5:$G5)'],
"Status": ['SUCCESS', 'FAIL', 'SUCCESS', 'FAIL', 'FAIL'],
"Value": [10, 15, 20, 25, 30],
"Value2": [130, 35, 3, 225, 40],
"Value 3": [10, 5, 44, 3000, 120],
})


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\test\\test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, 'TEST', startrow=0, startcol=0)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['TEST']



workbook.close()
writer.save()
```

The excel formulas work all except the "=COUNTIF($E2:$G6;"10")"

**I know that in this case I can avoid the double quotes because the value it is a number, but this is only an example, my problem is check alphanumeric value **

When I open the file, this is error appear.

[image]

Comment: There's a lot of missing information here. You don't explain how Excel is supposed to read your Python dictionary. You don't explain what Excel-related Python modules that you are using, if any. Are you using Pandas? Are you using `openpyxl` or any of the other modules discussed at http://www.python-excel.org, such as `xlsxwriter` or `xlrd`? Are you trying to use the `csv` module? You also should look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am sorry, you are right.
I am using pandas, and i convert my dictionary in dataframe before use df.to_excel()

I have try setting cell value also with df.loc

df_empList.loc[index, column] = '=COUNTIF(E6:NF6;"V")'

This working always only with formula without double quote.

I have added some information in my post

Comment: Please edit your code to be a [mre] so I can paste it into a file and __without adding anything__ run it to see the problem you are having.

Comment: I have post the minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem!

This not work: `=COUNTIF(E2:G2; "10")`
This work `=COUNTIF(E2:G2, "10")`

In my excel version, formulas use ";" between arguments, but in python I must use the ",".
In excel the formula appers in any case with ";"